# ng-if condition not working properly [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ng-if

When i click comment or reply link the form is opening up for all the cards. How to make to a particular scope such that the form should only open for which the link is clicked.

The below function is used with ng-if in the html to hide the form.Once clicked it should open only the corresponding form.

```
 $scope.increaseReply = function(object) {
   object.replyone += 1;
 };
```

[Here is plukr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGAYNWjBeTYXcqbcnq3H?p=preview)

Comment: Your mistake here is you are binding the same object (_reply) to all the instance of the comment sections. instead try different object with each one then try it out.

Comment: Yes, as @JenishRabadiya said, you are using same object '_reply' for every ng-if, either create an array of objects or create different object every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign replyActive bit for each comment. To do that, you can use iteration objects (I assumed you are using ng-repeat). You can add one more property to your object interactively and use it freely.

Simple example;

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.commentList = [
     {
       "author": "Tugca Eker",
        "comment": "You should check this example..."
      },
      {
       "author": "Gagan",
        "comment": "ng-if not working"
      },
      {
       "author": "Tugca Eker",
        "comment": "Check it again"
      }
    ];
   
}
```

```css
ul li{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="comment in commentList" ng-init="comment.isReplyActive = false;">
      <b>{{comment.author}}</b>: {{comment.comment}}
      <br />
      <a ng-click="comment.isReplyActive = !comment.isReplyActive;">Reply Now!</a>
      <div ng-if="comment.isReplyActive">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 
</div>
```

Snippet on Stackoverflow fails, I don't know why. Check this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7762/